# Having trouble getting text to stay to the left

Tags: html, css, css-position

See the [image] icon in my jsfiddle? It stays in place and doesn't move no matter what the screen width is.

However, the text next to it isn't acting in the same way.

I want the text to be RIGHT next to the [image] icon and not move at all even when the div is made smaller from changing the windows width resulting in hiding some of the text.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zmLL65gL/7/)**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.row {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 display: inline-block
}
.row.blockDisplay {
 display: block;
}
.column_60 {
 width: 55%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left:1%;
}
.column_40 {
 width: 44%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.columns {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 color: #A5A5A5;
 line-height: 24px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.row .columns p {
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
}


.left_half {
 background-color: #52BAD5;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
.right_half {
 background-color: #01B2D1;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
 
 

@media (max-width: 320px) {

.secondary_header {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.columns {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0PX;
 padding-right: 0PX;
 padding-bottom: 0PX;
 padding-left: 0PX;
}

.column_40.left_half {
 width: 100%;
}
.column_60.right_half {
 width: 100%;
}


}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.columns {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.column_40.left_half {
 width: 100%;
}
.column_60.right_half {
 width: 100%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
.columns {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.container .columns p {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
}
}


.taskPreviewWrap{
 list-style:none;
 margin-left:-40px;
 margin-top:-5px;
 color:#194e8d;
 }
.taskPreviewWrap li {
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius:6px;
 background-color:#011222;
 padding-top:9px;
 margin-top:5px;
 }
.dragdotsicon{
 width:7px;
 height:20px;
 background: url(http://s32.postimg.org/qlhqncer9/dragdots.png);
 margin-left:14px;
 margin-top:9px;
 }
.t-Date {
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:9pt;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:-17px;
 margin-left:-197px;
 letter-spacing:-0.4px;
 }
.t-Date:after {
 content:"";
 width:1px;
 height:29px;
 background-color:#194e8d;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:-8px;
 margin-left:12px;
 }
.t-ShortDesc{
font-weight:bold;
 font-size:9pt;
 letter-spacing:-0.2px;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position:absolute;
 text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */
    width: 22%; /* change to your preferences */
    white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
 margin-left:24px;
 margin-top:-17px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row blockDisplay">

  <div class="column_40 left_half">
    <ul class="taskPreviewWrap">

      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want everything in this line to stay to the left</span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want everything in this line to stay to the left</span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want everything in this line to stay to the left</span>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="column_60 right_half">
    <h2 class="column_title">RIGHT COLUMN</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `text-align: left` to `.taskPreviewWrap li`.

On `.t-Date`, adjust `margin-left: -197px` to `margin-left: 40px` (for example).

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zmLL65gL/8/)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.row {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 display: inline-block
}
.row.blockDisplay {
 display: block;
}
.column_60 {
 width: 55%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left:1%;
}
.column_40 {
 width: 44%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
.columns {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 color: #A5A5A5;
 line-height: 24px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: justify;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.row .columns p {
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-right: 10%;
}


.left_half {
 background-color: #52BAD5;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
.right_half {
 background-color: #01B2D1;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
@media (max-width: 320px) {

.secondary_header {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.columns {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0PX;
 padding-right: 0PX;
 padding-bottom: 0PX;
 padding-left: 0PX;
}

.column_40.left_half {
 width: 100%;
}
.column_60.right_half {
 width: 100%;
}


}

@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.columns {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
.column_40.left_half {
 width: 100%;
}
.column_60.right_half {
 width: 100%;
}
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
.columns {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.container .columns p {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
}
}

.taskPreviewWrap{
 list-style:none;
 margin-left:-40px;
 margin-top:-5px;
 color:#194e8d;
 }
.taskPreviewWrap li {
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius:6px;
 background-color:#011222;
 padding-top:9px;
 margin-top:5px;
    
    text-align: left; /* NEW */
 }
.dragdotsicon{
 width:7px;
 height:20px;
 background: url(http://s32.postimg.org/qlhqncer9/dragdots.png);
 margin-left:14px;
 margin-top:9px;
 }
.t-Date {
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:9pt;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:-17px;
 /* margin-left:-197px; */
    margin-left: 40px; /* NEW */
 letter-spacing:-0.4px;
 }
.t-Date:after {
 content:"";
 width:1px;
 height:29px;
 background-color:#194e8d;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:-8px;
 margin-left:12px;
 }
.t-ShortDesc{
font-weight:bold;
 font-size:9pt;
 letter-spacing:-0.2px;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position:absolute;
 text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */
    width: 22%; /* change to your preferences */
    white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
 margin-left:24px;
 margin-top:-17px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row blockDisplay">
  <div class="column_40 left_half">
    <ul class="taskPreviewWrap">
      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want all the text and dates in this line to stay to the left next to the dots icon instead of moving due to divs width expanding</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want all the text and dates in this line to stay to the left next to the dots icon instead of moving due to divs width expanding</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="dragdotsicon"></div>
        <span class="t-Date">05.18.16</span> 
        <span class="t-ShortDesc">I want all the text and dates in this line to stay to the left next to the dots icon instead of moving due to divs width expanding</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column_60 right_half">
    <h2 class="column_title">RIGHT COLUMN</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! Worked great. Appreciate your time!